# Extracting array with set::class utility

Tags: cakephp

Is there a way to extract the array for a specified id with the set::class utiliy? I can't figure out the XPath.

I.E. I would like to extract the array where the id = 1

```
[Document] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [id] => 1
                    [filename] => 1.txt
                )

            [1] => Array
                (
                    [id] => 2
                    [filename] => 2.txt
                )

            [2] => Array
                (
                    [id] => 3
                    [filename] => 3.txt
                )


        )
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

Set::extract('/[id=1]', $data['Document']);

or

Set::extract('/[id=1]/..', $data['Document']);

Comment: In my case Set::extract('/Document[id=1]', $document) worked.

Thanks again Neil